# How do I populate existing value in a mat-select dropdown?

Tags: javascript, angular, drop-down-menu, ngfor, mat-form-field

I have a mat-form-field that has a dropdown of data that i fetch from an API and I am able to select an option and save the picked option to the form successfully. However as I come back to that dropdown or reload, the saved value is not being shown and it looks like the value in that dropdown hasn't been selected.

The API is returning a list of objects like this

```
  [
     {
        personId: string,
        personName: string,
        personAge: int
      },
    ...
  ]
```

Im displaying the Name in the dropdown but saving the ID in the form

```
        <mat-form-field fxFlex.gt-sm="31%"  *ngIf="isPersonRequired()">
            <mat-label>
                Name
            </mat-label>
            <mat-select
                formControlName="personName"
                [required]="isPersonRequired()">

                <mat-option
                    *ngIf="(items | async)?.length==0"
                    disabled>

                    No item found
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option
                    *ngFor="let p of items | async"
                    [value]="p.personId">

                    {{p.personName}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
            <mat-error>
                Field Is Required
            </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Once a name has been selected and saved, how can i display it back when a user comes back to that page and dropdown?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the data on reload or refresh you can use localStorage to keep the data in browser storage until you don't need it anymore. To accomplish this I would recommend you to create a Shared Service to keep track of all the user selection then remove it when done. Here is an example of Shared Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharingService {
  private storageName: string = "Settings";

  constructor() { }

  setSettings(data: any) {
    localStorage.setItem(this.storageName, JSON.stringify(data));
  }

  getUserSettings() {
    let data = localStorage.getItem(this.storageName);
    return JSON.parse(data);
  }

  clearUserSettings() {
    localStorage.removeItem(this.storageName);
  }

  cleanAll() {
    localStorage.clear()
  }

}
```